# Grammer error for "with"

Tags: at-with

I wrote the following sentence:

> Our paper reviews flight scheduling, aircraft-path assignment, and gate assignment. Fig. 1 **shows** these activities.

After editing, Somebody suggested the following sentence:

> Our paper reviews flight scheduling, aircraft-path assignment, and gate assignment, **with** Fig. 1 **representing** these activities.

Is it correct or not?

Answer (score 1):

It is not incorrect, but I prefer the original version.

[This *NY Times* blogger](https://afterdeadline.blogs.nytimes.com/2009/03/09/metaphor-trouble/) sums it up nicely:

"Intent on adding more information or background, we frequently resort to cumbersome phrases beginning with “with,” and usually including a participle phrase or the equivalent. The construction isn’t wrong, but it’s often a signal that the sentence is becoming overly complex."